# Downloading entire S3 bucket with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I'm starting to look at switching my app from ASIHTTPRequest to something else, probably AFNetworking, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to start. I need the app to download an entire bucket's contents, including files in directories, into the app's bundle (with the same directories duplicated from the bucket to the bundle). There are likely to be several thousand small files in the bucket.

Any ideas for where to start? Can the AFNetworking S3 Client do this? Or should I be using the Amazon SDK? Or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking S3 Client is still in early stage of development. You should probably consider using the Amazon SDK...